# Add user to existing role in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using https://github.com/romanbican/roles to manage user roles. I am trying to set a user's role to an existing role.

I can create a new role via:

```
$role = Role::create([
  'name' => 'Admin',
  'slug' => 'admin'
]);

$user = User::find($id)->attachRole($role);
```

which works fine. The problem is setting the role to an existing role. There is the `attachRole` method which accepts an id. I assumed the id of the role. It'd be nice if I can just do `attachRole('admin');`

It isn't very clear how to do this in the docs. I've tried simply creating the role again but I get a duplicate role error, as expected. Sorry if this is a noob question, I just started with L5 yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the package but you should be able to retrieve the role model and use that:

```
$role = Role::where('slug', 'admin')->first();
$user = User::find($id)
if($role && $user){
    $user->attachRole($role);
}
else {
    // either role or user not found
}
```

Comment: ok, I think this is working, however, it is leaving the users initial role attached so I think I need to first `detachRole()` then `attachRole()`. I will report back

Comment: That's exactly what you would need to do :)

Comment: so this is what I have and seems to be working. `detachAllRoles()` seems to work fine and I didn't have to pass anything. Does any of this look incorrect? http://pastie.org/10023420 Also, `$user->role = ($newRole) ? $newRole : null;` is just so my blade template can select the proper radio button

Comment: I don't think you need to set `$user->role = $newRole` after you already attached it. Otherwise it looks correct to me

Comment: I am using it in my blade template to set the proper radio button. http://pastie.org/10023442 Since I just started with laravel, chances there's an easier way to do that. Can you suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: Firstly, I'd pass all available roles as an array from the controller to the view. Then in the view I'd loop over all roles and generate the radio buttons for each of it. If you need more help with that I encourage you to ask a new question here on SO so others might profit from it as well. (since it's not really on topic for this question)

Comment: ok that is a good suggestion, thanks for all the help. I think I can figure out the loop part